# What are reasons why one would want to use NSFileWrapper style packages in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilewrapper

If one is not using iCloud, is there any benefit to using `NSFileWrapper` style packages in an iOS application?

It seems that the only benefit to `NSFileWrapper` is that you can double-click on the package in the Finder to open it. However, on iOS, the Finder doesn't exist. So `NSFileWrapper` seems overkill, and adds unneeded complexity to the code. Am I missing something?